Perfect powers as products of two Fibonacci or Lucas numbers
The well-known Fibonacci sequence $(F_n)_{n\ge0}$ and Lucas sequence $(L_n)_{n\ge0}$ are defined by
$$F_0=0,\ F_1=1,\ \text{and}\ F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}\ \text{for}\ n=1,2,3,\ldots,$$
and
$$L_0=2,\ L_1=1,\ \text{and}\ L_{n+1}=L_n+L_{n-1}\ \text{for}\ n=1,2,3,\ldots,$$
respectively. Note that $F_2=1<F_3=2<F_4=3<\ldots$ and $L_1=1<L_2=3<L_3=4<\ldots$.
For $k,m\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$, we call the number $k^m$ a perfect power.
In 2006, Y. Bugeaud, M. Mignotte and S. Siksek [Annals of Math. 163 (2006), 969-1018] proved that the only perfect powers in the Fibonacci sequence are $F_6=2^3$ and $F_{12}=12^2$, and $L_3=2^2$ is the only perfect power in the Lucas sequence.
Motivated by Question 484381, here I propose the following conjecture.
Conjecture. The number $F_3F_6=2^4$ is the only perfect power of the form $F_mF_n$ with $2<m<n$. Also,
$$L_0L_3=2^3,\ L_0L_6=6^2,\ L_1L_3=2^2$$
are the only perfect powers of the form $L_mL_n$ with $0\le m<n$.
Via Mathematica, I have verified the conjecture for $n\le 400$.
QUESTION. Can one prove the conjecture by modifying the Bugeaud-Mignotte-Siksek method suitably? Can one find a counterexaple to the conjecture?
Your comments are welcome!

I also conjecture that $F_mL_n$ with $m>2$ and $n\ge0$ is a perfect power if and only if the ordered pair $(m,n)$ is among
$$(3,0),,(3,3),,(4,2),,(3,6),,(6,0),,(6,1),,(6,3),,(6,6),,(12,1),,(12,3),,(24,12).$$ This has been verified for $m,n\le 500$.

I have finished the verification of the conjecture in the posting for $n\le 900$.

Suppose that $F_mF_n$ is a perfect power with $2<m<n$. If $(m,n)\le2$, then by Lucas' theorem we have $(F_m,F_n)=F_{(m,n)}=1$ and hence both $F_m$ and $F_n$ are perfect powers, thus $m=6<n=12$ by the Bugeaud-Mignotte-Siksek result. As $F_6F_{12}=2^3\times12^2$ is not a perfect power, we must have $(m,n)>2$.
